# unknown display

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, amd-graphics, unknown-device

I changed to the new **graphic card**

> [AMD/ATI] RV730 PRO [**Radeon HD 4650**]

ubuntu read the card but i got **UnknownDisplay** and can't change the resolution

I tried to add resolution 1280*1024 by xrandr and didn't work

i tried to reinstall ubuntu and doesn't help
when i use command

> lspci | grep VGA

```
 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730 PRO [Radeon HD 4650]
```

and i tried reinstall drive by using the command and it didn't fix

> ubuntu-drivers devices

and when type

> glxinfo -B

```
       lxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: X.Org (0x1002)
    Device: AMD RV730 (DRM 2.50.0 / 6.0.9-060009-generic, LLVM 13.0.1) (0x9498)
    Version: 22.0.5
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 1024MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
```

Comment: `how can i change resolution ?`

Comment: Not enough information to go on. What Ubuntu version? What make/model of PC? What was the old GPU? What drivers did you have installed for it? What make/model of screen? How is the screen connected, with what cable, from what port, to what port?